# Get the ID1 and ID2 where the sum is the max?

Tags: sql

Suppose you have two ID's

```
ID1    ID2    SUM
01     A      1,000
01     B      2,000
01     C      3,000
02     AA     500
02     BB     6,000
```

I am trying to get the ID1 and ID2 where the sum is the max, ie.,

```
ID1    ID2    SUM
01     C      3,000
02     BB     6,000
```

I am not sure how to write this query.

Comment: which sql database?

Answer (score 0):

for SQL-Server

```
declare @mytable as table (id1 int, id2 varchar(10), sum_ money)

insert into @mytable 
values
(01,     'A',      1000),
(01,     'B',      2000),
(01 ,    'C',      3000),
(02,     'AA',     500),
(02,     'BB',     6000)

select t.* 
from @mytable t
join (    --- get id1 and max sum
select 
id1,max(sum_) sum_
 from @mytable
 group by id1
 ) x on x.id1 = t.id1 and x.sum_ = t.sum_    --- match id1 and max sum to the original table
order by t.id1
```